# Attack scenarios of the new Bash vulnerability

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, attack-vector, bash, shellshock

Odds are that you're already aware of the newly discovered Bash bug. It can be tested using `env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'  bash -c "echo this is a test"`.

What yet I haven't understand is, what are the real attack scenarios of this vulnerability. I have read that most likely it's going to be HTTP requests, but how?

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to test a web server via HTTP request is to inject the bash command through the user agent. Example:

```
$ wget -U '() { :;}; /bin/bash -c "echo vulnerable"' http://example.com/some-cgi-script
```

If a 5XX server error is generated, it means that the server is probably vulnerable to an exploit. For possible attack scenarios, please refer to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68130/9312)

Please test this **on your own servers** - trying this on other people's servers may get you in trouble.

Comment: On OSX without `wget`, try `curl -A '() { :;}; /bin/bash -c "echo vulnerable"' http://example.com/some-cgi-script`

Comment: I get a 301 server error.  I probably don't understand the above code, but does http://example.com/some-cgi-script point to a code on the victim's server or on the attacker's server (and contains malicious code) ?

Comment: @MattParkins, example.com is the server under attack. some-cgi-script is a script on example.com that enables the exploit to work. A 301 error means the client got redirected.

Comment: Thanks - so how does the attacker get the cgi script onto the victim's web server - I think that's what I'm not understanding.

Comment: @MattParkins, no, the CGI script is hosted by the victim, not inserted by the attacker.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see my mixup.  I was thinking http://example.com/some-cgi-script was a malicious script and didn't know how an attacker could get it on a victim's server, but actually it doesn't matter what CGI script is called.  Does it matter if the CGI script is actually there?

Comment: @MattParkins, yes, a CGI script must be present for such an attack.

Comment: example would be `http://example.com/script.cgi`, replace `example.com` and `/script.cgi` with your own address and cgi script(the script located on the server, not your computer)