# How to patch Bash on OSX in wake of "shellshock"?

Tags: macos, shellshock

My Mac is vulnerable, as this test shows:

`x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c :` ([source](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68177/41007))

I am using the version of bash that came with it. I also use Homebrew. What is the preferred way to patch Bash?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146851

Comment: Read [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146851) on apple.stackexchange

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you don't need to do this unless you are are offering web services to the public internet from your Mac. If you are not, wait until there is an official security update from Apple.

However, if you are offering web services, you might want to update.

### Official Patch

Apple has released an [Official Bash Security Update Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1769)

### Checking whether you are vulnerable

To confirm that you are using an outdated bash:

`$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

The most current bash is 4.3.25

### Unofficial Update Method: Compile Bash from Source Code using Homebrew

If you don't have Xcode installed, you'll need the Xcode command line tools, which can be installed by

`$ xcode-select --install`

Or from the developer portal `https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools` download `command_line_tools_for_osx_10.9_september_2014.dmg`

To install Brew (http://brew.sh):

`$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then do:

`$ brew doctor`

Follow any instructions if there are problems. Many common problems are addressed at `http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#troubleshoot-homebrew`

Then update brew to the latest list of packages:

`$ brew update`

To get the latest bash 4.3.25:

`$ brew install bash`

This installs bash into `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash`

The old `bash` and `sh` still exists at `/bin`, so after installing you'll rename the old executables to a new file.

`$ sudo mv /bin/bash /bin/bash_old
$ sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh_old`

If you are very paranoid, you can remove execute permissions on the `bash_old`

`$ sudo chmod a-x /bin/bash_old /bin/sh_old`

Then create a symbolic link to the new bash 4.3.25 that brew installed.

`$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash /bin/bash
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash /bin/sh`

Reboot and it is complete.

A warning — this may break some existing shell scripts that might rely on bash 3.2 or the differences that the Mac `sh` has over the linux `sh`. There is a much more sophisticated answer to replacing bash and sh from sources at
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-and-cve-2014-7

In most cases it is best to wait for official updates.

-- Christopher Allen

Comment: What about possible issues with DHCP exploits? (https://www.trustedsec.com/september-2014/shellshock-dhcp-rce-proof-concept/)

Comment: You can patch to avoid DHCP exploits if you are a sophisticated user with a Mac on the open internet, but I don't recommend that people patch unless they are actively offering web services. Just wildly taking advice and patching everything yourself is not a good idea unless you are a security professional, or there is a real need.

The goal of this post was to inform people that might not be very sophisticated at the shell, but may be offering web services from their Mac that they believe is important, and thus they want this patch now.

Comment: I am told, but can't confirm, that Apple's default DHCP is not vulnerable to Shellshock, because the Mac's DHCP does not call a shell script when a lease has expired like it does on Linux.

Comment: According to a colleague, brew will symlink bash anyway. On top of that if your PATH is correct, it shouldn't be much of an issue.

Another thing to note is that symlinking sh to bash pretty much broke my shell entirely. I undid that one...

Comment: FWIW, A couple people at my current workplace followed these instructions to upgrade Bash and rendered their Macs un-bootable. We had to get in to the recovery console, unlock the Macintosh HD, and use Terminal to move the binaries back. I'm wondering if the Apple built-in bash and sh have something special needed for encrypted volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of bash in brew before you do below step:

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash /bin/bash

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash /bin/sh

The bash version is updated to 4.3.27 so far. if you still link 4.3.25 to /bin/bash, you Mac should not boot. 
if you have do that, you can boot to recovery mode and copy /bin/bash_old to /bin/bash and copy /bin/sh_old to /bin/sh.

My bash version in brew is 4.3.27, so this will work for me:

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.27/bin/bash /bin/bash

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.27/bin/bash /bin/sh

Answer (score -1):

Not good, still vulnerable!

bash-4.3$ brew upgrade bash
Error: bash-4.3.25 already installed

bash-4.3$ /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.25/bin/bash
bash-4.3$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo this is a test"

vulnerable

this is a test