# Why "() { :;};"?

Tags: exploit, shellshock

I was wanting to understand why the code below serves as a proof-of-concept for telling me whether my server is vulnerable or not. Moreover, how does the vulnerability work at lower-level?

```
$ env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable'
```

So when I run the command below

```
bash -c "echo test"
```

I can get either (meaning I am vulnerable):

```
vulnerable
bash: BASH_FUNC_x(): line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: BASH_FUNC_x(): line 0: `BASH_FUNC_x() () { :;}; echo vulnerable'
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x'
test
```

or (meaning I am not vulnerable):

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x'
test
```

Comment: You can read the answer of Stephane (who discovered the bug) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157381/when-was-the-shellshock-cve-2014-6271-7169-bug-introduced-and-what-is-the-pat/157495#157495

Comment: Another great read: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/is-there-a-short-command-to-test-if-my-server-is-secure-against-the-shellshock-b/68177#68177

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the command you execute would be:

```
$ env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test"
```

It all boils down to the way the vulnerability works. When bash exports functions, it does so through the environment, with a function x stored in either variable x or (after latest patch) BASH_FUNC_x.

bash code then detects that the value begins with '() {' and runs:

```
x () { :;}; echo vulnerable
```

(that is the environment entry with `=` replaced with a space) which is a function definition with : in the body (a do-nothing command). In a CVE-2014-6271 vulnerable bash, it would execute the function definition (up to the `}`), and then go on executing the rest of the code (the initial patch then made it not execute the rest of the code).