# Is server exploitable by Shellshock with cgi-enabled only?

Tags: penetration-test, shellshock, bash

A server with vulnerable bash, but cgi enabled only and there are no cgi scripts in `cgi-bin`. Is it still exploitable ??

If there are scripts in cgi-bin and only server-admin knows about filenames of scripts in cgi-bin.
Is it exploitable by attacker?

How can attacker get to know about names of scripts in cgi-bin?
What are the default script names present in most cgi-enabled servers?

Comment: I read that it might also work if the server side scripts (e.g. php) call an external program, bash may get called (e.g. a system command for ImageMagick or for sendmail).

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which server; is it Apache?  At the moment, it appears that an attacker must be able to cause a CGI program to run in order to exploit the vulnerability. Having no CGI scripts would seem to offer some protection. Removing mod_cgi from httpd.conf would offer more:

```
a2dismod cgi
apache2ctl graceful
```

The second part of your question relies on security by obscurity, which is always a bad idea.

Here's a list of potential CGI scripts/programs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vN2QOG2OZIAHGXDmd5wB8FPi-Hin2GaIlWRJ0RYkTbA/edit  I didn't compile this list, and have not attempted to vet it for completeness.

Comment: How would you have to check your server against this list?

Comment: https://shellshock.detectify.com/ will do it for you.  (I haven't vetted this.)

Comment: https://shellshock.detectify.com/
 will iterate over a list of possible cgi-URLs until it finds a vulnerable end-point where it will inject a harmless payload.